# Find My Friends app accuracy

Tags: sharing, find-my-iphone, geolocation, find-my-friends

I have my boyfriend's location on the Find My Friends app and he has mine as well.

Normally his location appears to hops around a bit when it's loading on my screen, but it's usually in the same 2-3 spots. However, the other night while it was loading, his location appeared to be some distance across the street, and then when it loaded it appeared to be in the middle of the street.

Normally it is a little off, but still closer to his house then it was the other night.

Is it normal that the location can appear to hop around a little, or for it to be a little off?

Comment: Find my iPhone is not always accurate. It's off sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The exact location shown by the Find My Friends (or the Find My iPhone) service can be off somewhat, and the distances can be a lot more than what you've described.

For example, in our household we have about 20 devices. We also live on acreage and back onto an environment reserve. Sometimes, when using the Find My iPhone service, I can see one or more devices appear as if they're in our next door neighbour's yard, somewhere within the bush surrounds of the reserve, in the creek, and so on.

So, while it's impossible for anyone here to give you any certainty on where your boyfriend's device was at the time, we can say that the location being reported could easily be off by a distance of more than just appearing to be across the street. It's also common for it to appear to hop or jump around a little while obtaining the location.

Comment: Very occasionally it can get even more bizarre than that. if someone moves house & takes their wifi router with them, they can skew geolocation results for weeks until the location mappers catch up. Also, if ISPs change their IP lease settings - mine did that a couple of years ago & I appeared to live in Bristol for a month... 120 miles from home.